# Why isn't my subclassed UItableView scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder

I'm writing an iOS 5 app (in Xcode 4.3, using Storyboards and ARC) that has some table cells that need to respond to horizontal pans. I had a table setup that worked really well but then I needed to implement the same behavior on another scene. I figured the best-practices way would be to abstract out the gesture-recognizing and -handling code into subclasses. But now the tableView won't scroll, and the solution I had for this problem under the old method doesn't help.

I have a `RestaurantViewController` which inherits from `UIViewController` and has a property `ULPanningTableView *tableView`. Some of the table's cells are `MenuItemCell`s and inherit from  `ULPanningTableViewCell`. The table's delegate and data source are the `RestaurantViewController`.

`ULPanningTableViewCell` inherits from `UITableViewCell` and is pretty close to the original, the only difference being that it has properties to keep track of the cell's front and back views, and the custom backgrounds.

`ULPanningTableView` is a bit more complicated, since it has to set up the recognition and handling.

`ULPanningTableView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ULPanningTableView : UITableView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) float openCellLastTX;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *openCellIndexPath;

- (id)dequeueReusablePanningCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer;
// ... some helpers for handlePan:

@end
```

and `ULPanningTableView.m`:

```
#import "ULPanningTableView.h"
#import "ULPanningTableViewCell.h"

@implementation ULPanningTableView

@synthesize openCellIndexPath=_openCellIndexPath, openCellLastTX=_openCellLastTX;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Table View Helpers

- (id)dequeueReusablePanningCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    ULPanningTableViewCell *cell = (ULPanningTableViewCell *)[self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // for testing: only allow UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizers to begin
    NSString *gr = NSStringFromClass([gestureRecognizer class]);
    if ([gr isEqualToString:@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer"]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

#pragma mark - panhandling

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
    // ...
}
// ... some helpers for handlePan:

@end
```

I've played around with `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, because that was how I solved this problem back when these weren't separate classes (`ULPanningTableView` stuff was implemented inside `RestaurantViewController` and `ULPanningTableViewCell` was stuff was implemented in `MenuItemCell`. I would essentially return NO for gestures where the `translationInView` was more vertical than horizontal). Anyway, I can't get the table to scroll! I can get the pan gestures to be recognized if I return YES from `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, or if I remove the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` implementation entirely.

I'm still a beginner in iOS, and in Objective-C, so I only have hunches based on things I've read, and I'm under the impression from a [similar problem](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-640508.html) that the culprit is `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer` doing voodoo with the responder chain...

I would greatly appreciate any light you can shed on this!

Comment: Are you trying to move a view in the cell or are you trying to scroll the cell's contents horizontally?

Comment: Horizontal pan should move a view in the cell. I couldn't figure out how to interact with the cell's contents to show its `backgroundView`, so I'm moving a custom property of the cell `UIView *frontView`. Vertical pan should scroll the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I feel really silly. `-handlePan:` is already a method! I changed it to `-handleCustomPan:` and it will handle other pans normally. I'm not sure why it wasn't crashing, but there it is. Oh, and I had to keep the UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer edge case in `-gestureRecognizerDidBegin:`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSString *gr = NSStringFromClass([gestureRecognizer class]);
    if ([gr isEqualToString:@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer"]) {
        // allow scroll to begin
        return YES;
    } else if ([gr isEqualToString:@"UIPanGestureRecognizer"]){
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        // allow horizontal pans to begin
        ULPanningTableViewCell *cell = (ULPanningTableViewCell *)[panGR view];
        CGPoint translation = [panGR translationInView:[cell superview]];
        BOOL should = (fabs(translation.x) / fabs(translation.y) > 1) ? YES : NO;

        if (!should) {
            [self closeOpenCellAnimated:YES];
        }

        return should;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",gestureRecognizer);
        return NO;
    }
}
```